# Category page http to https IIS rewrite rule

Tags: iis, https, url-rewriting, iis-8

I want my website to be normal http link ex:http://www.example.com
but same time the category page should be with https ex:https://www.example.com/Category/

I have SSL configured for whole domain and explicitly I have had put a rule of HTTPS to HTTP for whole domain and it's working fine.

But I want the internal category page to work on HTTPS, please help me with IIS rewrite URL for this.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show me you current Rewrite Rules (and Rewrite Map's if you are using them)?

Comment: <rule name="Force NonHTTPS except Category" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^category/?" negate="true" />
    <conditions>
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
    </conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}" />
</rule>

Comment: ok the above rule is working fine ,but the page "Category" is a order page and after Checkout i am returning to the same page and not to see the status page ,it's like redirecting to same page again ex:https://www.example.com/category/checkout

but i want ex : https://www.example.com/category/checkout/ordersuccess